# Link between 2 dataets with outerjoin in MicroStrategy Dossiers

Tags: microstrategy, dossier

Now I'm developing the dossiers report in MicroStrategy. But I'm encountering the technical difficulty about Join behavior.

I have 2 tables like below.

[Product List Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MD9N.png)

[Product Status Master Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsqgA.png)

I set up the attribute link with "Name" in Product Status Master Table and "Current Phase" in Product List Table.
Then, I created the table chart like below.
[Actual Result of Join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHDAn.png)

I only would like to show Product List Table left out join with Product Status Master Table.
but "0" lines are dispalyed without my intention.

I tried to select InnerJoin and OuterJoin configuration again and again but not meet my expectation.

Could you please give me some advices?

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOYiW.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason by myself.
I needed to add at least one metaric dataset in the chart.
after adding one metric dataset, the result is what I expected.

here is the reference of this solution.
[KB441281 - Microstrategy](https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB441281-Explanation-for-the-join-behavior-setting-works-on-data-blending-datasets-inside-of-Dossiers-or-Documents-in-MicroStrategy?language=ja)